# static struct with raw pointer gives "`core::marker::Sync` is not implemented..."

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi

I am trying to create some static data structures in Rust that will be passed to C code.  Below is a minimal example that fails to compile, and I have no idea what the error means in this context.  So the question is, why is it failing and how do I fix it?

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub name: *const str,
}

static mystruct: MyStruct = MyStruct {name: "why!!!\0"};

// src/lib.rs:52:29: 52:56 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `*const str`
// src/lib.rs:52 static mystruct: MyStruct = MyStruct {name: "why!!!\0"};
//                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, [`Sync` means "can be safely shared between tasks when aliased"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html). Rust considers types that contain raw pointers to not be shareable between threads by default, and a static variable needs to be shareable.

If you have reasons to believe that your type is indeed shareable between threads with no problem, then you can assert to the compiler that you know better:

```
unsafe impl Sync for MyStruct { }
```

If you have control over the C library however, I would encourage lifting the requirement that the struct needs to be static - maybe designing the library around a handle of some sort.